# Does #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(1) mean master thread will execute it?

Tags: openmp

If I start a parallel region with a number of threads 1, is it guaranteed that no new threads will be started (hence, there will be no overhead) and the master thread will execute that region?

In other words, can we guarantee that this code will increment all elements of A:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(1)
    for(int i=0; i< 1e6; ++i){
#pragma omp master
        A[i]++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The intention of your code is not entirely clear. By using the `parallel for` combined directive you start sharing the work between the threads. Then you restrict the body of the loop to the master thread of the team thus no work sharing may occur. This is ambiguous.

The OpenMP specification handles this ambiguity explicitly in [Section 2.20](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse28.html#x143-6330002.20). The solution is simple: **You may not do it in a conforming program**.

> A master region may not be closely nested inside a worksharing, loop,
>   atomic, task, or taskloop region.

Comment: The intention is an illustrative purpose. The real code I am running uses runtime variables to set # of threads. I wanted to know what happens when evaluating those conditions leaves just 1 thread to execute parallel section. I was running profiler and it looks like even though I restricted the number of threads to 1, still, the work was not done by master thread and additional thread was started to execute the parallel region. That looks like a waste